# OpenCV object detection from face detection code - ANDROID

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, object-detection

I was wondering if you can use the face detection opencv sample code and slot in a new xml file trainied to recognise the object you wanted it to.

would this work?

if not how do you do it, I have looked a few sites mainly [site](https://sites.google.com/a/forstersfreehold.com/visible-kitteh-project/home/announcements/tutorial4buildingacascadeclassifierfile-placeholder) where it seems to suggest that its done somehow along those lines but I can't seem to get it to work, so was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, that's possible.

the cascade classifier just finds, what the cascade-file was trained on, be it faces, eyes or soda-cans.

[lots of existing examples here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data) , and ofc, you can train your own, opencv comes with tools for that ( cascade_training, haar_training )